# How to use std::allocator in custom container properly?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I'm trying to develop my own container which will implement hash table. The main requirement is that this container must be compatible with STL. Now I can't catch how to allocate memory and initialize objects for internal container needs.

The main question is how to manage keys for such container? Do I need to allocate another storage for indexes produced by hash function from keys? And then link them to actual storage with node buckets?

There are template parameters for my container.

```
template<
    class Key, class T, class Hasher = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
class my_hashtable_v1 {
```

But then I use internal member types like this to allocate nodes for my container.

```
template<class T>
struct ch_node_t : hash_node {
    template<class... Args>
    ch_node_t(Args&&... args) : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
    }
    T value;
};

using node_type = ch_node_t<T>;
using storage_allocator_ = typename Alloc::template rebind<node_type>::other;
```

Is it correct to allocate nodes this way? This is piece of code from `insert` method.

```
auto node = &storage_[slot];
if(!node_traits::is_allocated(*node)) {
  new(node) node_type(v.second);
  node_traits::link_head(*node);
  --freelist_;
}
```

Where `storage` is pointer to allocated pool. That's how I allocated pool:

```
storage_ = storage_allocator_.allocate(size_);
```

And main thing that I can't understand is how to manage nodes keys using `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>` properly? I need to create something like index and storage separately?

Exploring `std::unordered_map` code is too hard to get those answers, that's why I ask you for direction in my developing custom container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allocate for objects of another type (let's call it `Node`) than `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type` (let's call it `T`), where `Alloc` is the possibly custom allocator type, you must `rebind` the allocator to get an allocator for the type `Node`:

```
using node_alloc_t = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<Node>;
node_alloc_t node_alloc;
node_alloc.allocate(size_);
```

> But how to deal with keys properly? Do I need to create another storage for indexes?

You don't necessarily need to create separate storage for keys. You can store them within nodes. This is how tree based containers work for example.

> And my node type don't contain any key.

If you want to store the keys separately, then you do need to allocate storage for them.

Comment: I use alias for that

`using storage_allocator_ = typename Alloc::template rebind<node_type>::other;`

But how to deal with keys properly? Do I need to create another storage for indexes? Because I have to apply hash function to key. And my node type don't contain any key.

Comment: @powercat note that the `rebind` member is deprecated, and removed in c++20. You should use `std::allocator_traits::rebind_alloc` like in my example.

Comment: @powercat see edt.

Comment: thanks for note about C++20! Ok, then I'll try to store keys inside nodes.